# Cant't reuse the stacklayout in Generic List in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I am creating set of stacklayout with different views and adding it to the **List< StackLayout >** in a singleton class.
When I create a new page and use the list of stacklayout it works as expected. But when I use the same list in second page it throws a null pointer exception and unable to add list of stacklayout in the second page.

**Singleton Class:**

```
  public class SessionData
  {

    private static SessionData _instance;
    public static SessionData Instance
    {
        get{
            if (_instance == null)
                _instance = new SessionData ();

            return _instance;
        }
    }
   public List<StackLayout> Views { get; set; } //List of stacklayout views
  }
```

**Adding Views in ContentPage:**

```
  StackLayout Scrollcontentview = new StackLayout ();
  var temp = SessionData.Instance.Views ;
  foreach (var content in temp) 
  {
            if(content != null)
            {
                Scrollcontentview.Children.Add(content );
            }
  }
```

If I use code **Adding Views in ContentPage** (which is given above) in **Page1** it works, and when I navigate to **Page2** and use the same code it fails.

I don't know where I'm going wrong. If anyone knows the solution for this, sharing it will be really helpful.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you can't reuse a visual element multiple times in the view hierarchy.

Longer answer: avoid using singletons. if you really want to reuse a StackLayout, you have to make sure you remove it from its parent first.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, You mean I have to remove **page1** from the navigation stack while navigating to **page2** or Remove all views from **page1's** Parent StackLayout while navigating to **page2**

Comment: if you want to reuse a stacklayout from page1 into page2, you'll have to remove the stacklayout from page1's children before adding it to page2. But you'd better _not_ try to reuse the views, and share the view models instead.

Comment: please provide a repro